# Storing and retrieving a long array from NSUserDefaults

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

How can I store a long array into `NSUserDefaults` and retrieve it?

Here is how my long array looks:

```
long *arr;
arr = new long [10];
for(int i = 0 ; i<10 ; i++)
{
arr[i] = i;
}
```

Now I want to store this `arr` into `NSUserDefaults` and then retrieve it later

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can only store objects in NSUserDefaults. So you have to convert the array to an `NSArray`. However, NSArrays also only store objects, so you need to store the `long` values encapsulated in an `NSNumber` object:

```
//saving
NSUserDefaults *standardDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSMutableArray *arrayObj = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

long *arr;
arr = new long [10];

for(int i = 0 ; i<10 ; i++) {
    [arrayObj addObject:[NSNumber numberWithLong:arr[i]]];
}

[standardDefaults setObject:arrayObj forKey:@"longArray"];
[arrayObj release];


//reading
NSUserDefaults *standardDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSArray *arrayObj = [standardDefaults objectForKey:@"longArray"];

long *arr;
arr = new long [10];

for(int i = 0 ; i<10 ; i++) {
    arr[i] = [(NSNumber*)[arrayObj objectAtIndex:i] longValue];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

By using a [NSArray](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html) — not plain c-array

```
NSUserDefaults *standardUserDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

[standardUserDefaults setObject:myNSArray forKey:@"Prefs"];
```

Retrieve:

```
NSArray *array = [standardUserDefaults objectForKey:@"Prefs"];
```