# how to implement code for saving multiple array items through the alertview?

Tags: iphone, ios5

I have implemented code for alert view with textfield here when i click on ok button the textfield entered value is storing in string formate as (str) and i am adding that value to the array in order to i am loading array to the table view but here problem is every time table view consists one item but i want store multiple items entering items from alert and save it as array item for this how to implement code for saving multiple array items through the alertview any one help me to solve this problem in iphone.

```
myAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Enter year" 
                                     message:@"alert message" 
                                    delegate:self 
                           cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" 
                           otherButtonTitles:@"Ok", nil];
[myAlert addTextFieldWithValue:@"" label:@"entervalue"];     
alertTextField=[myAlert textFieldAtIndex:0];
alertTextField.keyboardType=UIKeyboardTypeAlphabet;
alertTextField.clearsOnBeginEditing=YES;
alertTextField.clearButtonMode=UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
alertTextField.keyboardAppearance=UIKeyboardAppearanceAlert;
[myAlert show];
[myAlert release];


-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    NSString *buttonTitle=[alertView buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];
    if ([buttonTitle isEqualToString:@"Ok"]) {

        str = alertTextField.text;

        [savedarray addObject:str];
    }
}
```

Comment: check whether your array is allocated when you show the alert.If yes , then declare or allocate it only once so that array wil keep the values.

Comment: For that you should ADD all str in different different index value and use for loop of index value for that.After that your all string add in array in different index

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
  NSString *buttonTitle=[alertView buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];
  if ([buttonTitle isEqualToString:@"Ok"]) {

    str = alertTextField.text;

    [savedarray addObject:str];
    [self.yourtableview reloadData]; // reload your tableview when add new data in array.
  }
}




- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section        {
return savedarray.count;
 }

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}
cell.textLabel.text = [savedarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];    
return cell;
}
```

Hope, this will help you..

Comment: hi friend first of all i have a great thankful to you for giving your suggestion .i tried above code.it is working perfectly but after restart the application i lose all savedarray items.How will i save those items until uninstall the application.

Comment: for that you two option 1) use sqlite ,core data 2) use plist to store your string

Comment: i tried to save strings data by using NSUSerdefaults but it didn't work.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4546930/storing-and-retrieving-a-long-array-from-nsuserdefaults   ....visit this post and use accepted ans...enjoy

Answer (score 0):

If i am rit u r asking for something like this:

```
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
 NSString *buttonTitle=[alertView buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];
 if ([buttonTitle isEqualToString:@"Ok"]) 
 {
     str = alertTextField.text;
     if([savedarray Count] < yourRequiredItemsCount)
     {
      [savedarray addObject:str];
      alertTextField = @"";
      [alertView show];
     }
     else
     {
      [alertView release];                //Release the Alert here.
     }
 }
}
```

tell me if it helps! will give u an alternate sol.

Answer (score 0):

If you're allocating the savedarray correctly, then the posted code looks reasonable.  The next thing to check is whether you are properly using savedarray as the datasource for the table.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return savedarray.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = [savedarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];    
    return cell;
}
```

Be sure to set the same view controller as the tableview's delegate and datasource.